# Дизайн сайта

Tags: дизайн

Через сколько лет дизайн, построение блоков и т.д. на сайте устаревает. Например сейчас оно новое, через сколько лет оно будет старое и уродливое? Раз во сколько лет на сайте надо делать редизайн меняя архитектуру и т.д. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не буду швыряться ссылками с гугла, просто скопипастю.

» Иногда возникает вопрос: Что это такое и зачем это надо? Ответ очень прост - редизайн сайта это изменение его текущего дизайна на новый, в соответствие с последними изменениями в области графики и с соблюдением фирменного стиля заказчика. Редизайн сайта делается для обновления сайта, например если сайт давно существует само собой появляется необходимость изменения дизайна созданного сайта, т.к. появляются все новые и новые сайты с современным дизайном, и отставать от последних новинок нельзя, ведь все в Интернете очень быстро распространяется и есть необходимость постоянно следить за этими изменениями.

» Допустим вы давно создали свой сайт, что вы теряете, если не делаете редизайна - это уменьшение целевой аудитории сайта, т.к. дизайн сильно влияет на приток посетителей, ведь если дизайн сайта не нравится его конечному пользователю, он вряд-ли зайдет на него снова, т.к. необходима динамично изменяющаяся информация. Наличие качественного дизайна позволит Вам конкурировать по этому показателю с другими сайтами схожей тематики, что может от сайта с более тусклым дизайном переманить некоторый объем сетевого трафика для Вашего сайта, что изменит и Ваше положение в выдаче поисковой системы, т.к. отнюдь не последнее место у поисковых систем играет фактор посещаемости ресурса.

» Редизайн сайта необходим всем сайтам, вопрос только во времени существования и качественности предыдущего дизайна, в основном срок жизни профессионального дизайна составляет примерно 2-3 года, после чего рекомендуется изменять дизайн сайта для того, чтобы сайт был более привлекателен и для его пользователей, и для поисковых систем, которые влияют на выдачу сайта в поисковых системах.

» Редизайн это то же самое, что и дизайн для сайта, создается либо с нуля либо с использованием старого стиля сайта, когда делается только увеличение качества изображений, видеоматериалов и заставок на сайте, но основным все же является первый пункт. Для сайта сначала идет оценка, стоит ли вообще переделывать текущий дизайн, после чего разрабатывается новый макет, по которому после его одобрения со "старого" сайта идет перенос информации на обновленный.

» Обычно компании замечают, что дизайн сайта пора менять когда сайт теряет свою аудиторию, уменьшается количество продажи товаров или оказания услуг, т.е. клиентов, которых этот сайт к Вам направляет и возникает острая необходимость что-то менять. Не стоит откладывать редизайн сайта в долгий ящик, если вы считаете что Ваш сайт утратил свою былую популярность и качество.

Answer (score 7):

Вот представьте такую ситуацию - вы встречаетесь с девушкой (ну или в парнем, в зависимости от вашего пола и вкусов)...вы ее любите, цените и все такое...Но тут вдруг вы хлопаете себя по голове и говорите: "Ух ты, уже целых два года встречаемся...пора бы расставаться..нет, я, конечно, ее люблю и все такое, но все-таки уже два года, хватит уже"....Неестественно как-то, не так ли? Скорее всего, вы с ней расстанетесь по каким-то другим, более объективным причинам, а не потому что "уже два года". Надеюсь, понимаете аналогию?

Comment: Шикарно :)

Comment: в такой ситуации нужно было написать "блин уже два года прошло" и отправить девушку куда-нибудь под нож и шприц

Comment: да вы гуманист...я бы даже сказал, серийный гуманист

Answer (score 1):

Через пару лет. А если серьёзно, то на такой вопрос нет точного ответа.
 Можно сказать наверняка, что условный "промежуток" между редизайнами сайта в обозримом будущем будет несколько сокращаться.

Comment: А как Вы думаете будет ли адаптивный дизайн использоваться везде или же будет год, а потом из-за увилечения диагоналей экранов смартфонов  и улучшения процессоров просто станет не нужен?

Comment: Будет, но как и сейчас, не везде.

Comment: >условный "промежуток" между редизайнами сайта в обозримом будущем будет несколько сокращаться

хм..за счет чего?

Comment: Как мне кажется, из-за скорости развития ИТ и веба в частности.

Comment: и в чем же связь? Условный заказчик Вася Пупкин вряд ли закажет редизайн сайта только потому что CSS3 станет поддерживаться целиком каждым даже самым отсталым браузером вроде ишака. Ему вообще до фонаря всё развитие веба и IT. Он закажет этот редизайн только когда это будет нужно ему, и когда у него будут для этого средства. Да и новые айфоны-айпады с новыми супер-огромными разрешениями не станут чаще выходить

Answer (score 1):

Менять внутреннюю структуру (например с table на div) это на ваше усмотрение, имхо она должна быть максимально современной на момент создания.

Относительно дизайна, есть понятие как фирменный стиль. И любой состоявшийся проект должен ему следовать. Можете представить себе, что всем известный VK кардинально изменит дизайн. Шуму со стороны пользователей будет масса.

Изменения на рабочих проектах нужно вносить порциально, пользователи народ пугливый.

Измерить временным промежутком смену дизайна невозможно

Comment: фэйсбук несколько раз менял. кого волнует писк хомяков ?